# Display database search result in html using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to create a page, where I can search for case files from my database, however, I can't get my code to work.

I already have pages showing all content of the database and where I can add new content.

I've read guides, tutorials and questions on stackoverflow, but can't find an answer on how to proceed.

I have the following php code in searchcasescript.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or 
die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) or die("something went wrong");

if(isset($_GET["form_submit"]))
{
    $journalnummer =$_GET["journalnummer"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from testcases where journalnummer=? ");

        $stmt->bind_param("s",$journalnummer);

        $stmt->execute();
    $val = $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $val->num_rows;

    if($row_count >0)
    {
        $result =$val->fetch_assoc();

        print_r($result);
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong number";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}

?>
```

and my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="searchcasescript.php" method="post">
    <label for="journalnummer">Journalnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="journal" class="form-control" required> 
<div class="form-group"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" class="btn btn-basic" value="Søg">
</form>
```

I've had different results depending on my changes to the php, but currently I'm getting nothing. Pressing search opens a new, blank page.

What I would like to end up with was being able to enter full or part of a case number and the search results being displayed on the same or a new page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to read more about this and/or where to proceed with my code?

And apologies, if I've somehow missed the answer in one of the questions here.

UPDATED WITH "LIKE":

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM straffesager WHERE journalnummer LIKE ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", '%' . $journal . '%');
```

Comment: Your form uses `POST`, but your code uses `$_GET`

Comment: You're right, I missed that completely when trying out one more guide/answer to a question.

Changing $_GET to $_POST results in this error:
Notice: Undefined index: journalnummer in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\SearchCaseScript.php on line 30. 

I do have a column named "journalnummer", so I suspect that's not the problem. I've changed $journalnummer to $journal to reflect the name of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $journalnummer =$_GET["journalnummer"];
```

Your looking for journalnummer but your input has a name of journal

`<input type="text" name="journal" class="form-control" required>`

```
$_POST['journal'];
```

This is what should contain the number .

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you - I'd looked at it so many times, but didn't occur before now. 

Say, if I wanted the search to use "like" - where would I place it in the statement? "%=?%" ?

Comment: neither "journalnummer", "=" or "?" appears to be the searchterm in my SELECT, but maybe I just can't see it?

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE something LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", '%' . $journalnummer . '%');

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: doesn't seem to - I get this error instead: 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\SearchCaseScript.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\SearchCaseScript.php on line 58

Comment: Hmm , add your new code to the main question ( don't remove the old code just incase someone else has the same problem ). Just add it to the bottom so I can have a look.

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM straffesager WHERE journalnummer LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $journal);
$stmt->execute();